# Sign change for a continuous Lipschitz function

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose I have a Lipschitz function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$. Suppose there is a measure zero set on which $f$ is equal to $0$. Can the following happen?

For any $\epsilon > 0$, if $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$, $f$ takes both positive and negative values in $(x, x+ \epsilon)$ and also in $(x-\epsilon ,x)$?

What if $f$ were also differentiable?

Obviously, the above would not happen if $f$ never becomes negative, i.e. bounces off $0$. A counterexample regarding one sided derivatives of Lipschitz functions posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929977/does-a-lipschitz-continuous-function-have-one-sided-derivatives-everywhere) shows that at one point it can happen. But, I am interested in showing the following:

If, for some $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$, and for any $\epsilon > 0$, $f$ takes both positive and negative values in $(x, x+ \epsilon)$ and also in $(x-\epsilon ,x)$ then there are at least two points where $f$ changes sign, i.e. in some closed interval to the left it's negative and to the right it's positive,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f(c)=0.$ Then $f$ on $(c,b)$ takes positive and negative values. Let $d$ be such that $f(d)>0.$ Now let define $$e=\sup\{x\in (c,d)| f(x)=0\}.$$ It is clear that $e<d$ and $f(e)=0.$ Since $f(e)=0$ we have that on $(e,d)$ the function takes positive and negative values. Then there exist $z\in (e,d)$ such that $f(z)=0.$ This contradicts the definition of $e.$ So, we conclude that such a function can't exist.

Comment: Thanks. But $\{x\in (c,d) | f(x) = 0\}$ may be empty. The counterexample in the link has this property when $c = 0$.

Comment: No, it can't be empty. Since $f$ takes positive and negative values on $(c,d)$ there exist at least a point $x\in (c,d)$ such that $f(x)=0.$

Comment: sorry, it's sup, not inf! I thought you meant inf! Thanks a lot. Any thoughts on the last part, the one with at least two points where sign changes?